# Alertmanager, different interval for different alert rules

Tags: alert, prometheus

I'm using alertmanager to get alerts for prometheus metrics, I have different alert rules for different metrics, is it possible to set different interval for each alert rules, for example for metric1 I have rule1 and I need to check this rule on daily base interval, and for metric2 I have rule2 and this one should be check every 2 hours,

Comment: isn't enough to set the interval on the rule for `2 hours` like this `expr: avg without(cpu)(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}[2h]))`?

Comment: I don't know I'm using something like this: expr: node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}  for: 2h

Comment: I was studying better your problem. the `for: 2h` means that the alert have to be firing for 2 hours in order to be sent. You can use the alertmanager with different route tree

Answer (score 12):

The `for: 5m` property is used to ensure that the rule returns true for X continuous minutes before to trigger the alert. For example, in case that there is a spike in cpu usage for 30 seconds, the alert will not be triggered because we set the `for` property to 5 minutes. Hence this is not the right property for you.

I believe that you can use the `repeat_interval` of the alert manager to set the time interval to send notifications. Then you have the alert but you fire/trigger it depending on your `repeat_interval`. This [link](https://www.robustperception.io/whats-the-difference-between-group_interval-group_wait-and-repeat_interval) explains them in detail.

- `group_wait` sets how long to initially wait to send a notification for a particular group of alerts.
- `group_interval` dictates how long to wait before sending notifications about new alerts that are added to a group of alerts that have been alerted on before
- `repeat_interval` is used to determine the wait time before a firing alert that has already been successfully sent to the receiver is sent again.

In order to put them to work, you have to define `label`'s for each alert. For example, in my `alerts.yml` file I create labels `app_type: server` and `app_type: service`:

```
groups:
- name: monitor_cpu
  rules:
  - alert: job:node_cpu_usage:percentage_gt_50
    expr: 100 * node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="user"} / ignoring(mode) group_left sum(node_cpu_seconds_total) without(mode) > 5.5
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
      app_type: server
    annotations:
      summary: "High CPU usage"
      description: "Server {{ $labels.instance }} has high CPU usage."
- name: targets
  rules:
  - alert: monitor_service_down
    expr: up == 0
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
      app_type: service
    annotations:
      summary: "Monitor service non-operational"
      description: "Service {{ $labels.instance }} is down."
```

then I create a route tree to send notifications to different groups by matching the specific label. And here comes the solution that I use. I define different `group_wait`, `group_interval`, and `repeat_interval` for each group. Then you can use the `repeat_interval: 1h` and the `repeat_interval: 24h` in different `routes` leaf:

```
global:
  smtp_from: 'mail@gmail.com'
  smtp_smarthost: smtp.gmail.com:587
  smtp_auth_username: 'mail@gmail.com'
  smtp_auth_identity: 'mail@gmail.com'
  smtp_auth_password: ''

route:
  receiver: 'admin-team'
  routes:
    - match_re:
        app_type: (server|service)
      receiver: 'admin-team'
      routes:
      - match:
          app_type: server
        receiver: 'admin-team'
        group_wait: 1m
        group_interval: 5m
        repeat_interval: 1h
      - match:
          app_type: service
        receiver: 'dev-team'
        group_wait: 1m
        group_interval: 5m
        repeat_interval: 24h

receivers:
 - name: 'admin-team'
   email_configs:
   - to: 'admin-mail@gmail.com'

 - name: 'dev-team'
   email_configs:
   - to: 'dev-mail@gmail.com'
```

Unfortunately, I did not test for 24 hours but with a different gap of minutes and it worked. I think that it will work for long hours as well.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did it before, set  "for: 24h", but it seems this "for" is not working for times more than 20 minutes, I tried it as seconds and minutes too, here is my exact current rule:    rules:
  - alert: SSL_expiring
    expr: ( probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry - time() ) < 1209600 
    for: 1440m
    labels:
      severity: "critical"
    annotations:
      summary: "Server {{ $labels.instance }} SSL is expiring"

Comment: Also check if your promQL is correct on the graph dashboard. I am not able to parse your promQL as you wrote. Or try a simple promQL to verify

Comment: It's correct in my system, and it's sending alerts, but the important part is the "for: 1440m" or "for: 24h" does not work. it's sending alert every 2 hours as my "  evaluation_interval" is 2 hours, I can not increase it because I have other rules that should check every 2 hours,

Comment: Check this issue https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/2220#issuecomment-611908332 . they removed `scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s` and `scrape_interval: 5s` to make it work. Seems like a bug :(. Compare the prometheus version as well

Comment: it's not about repeat_interval actually evaluation_interval works well, I just need different evaluation_inteval  for each alert rules, I thought I can do it by using "for:" in alert rules file but it's just working when "for: time" time is less than 20 minutes, any time more than 20 minutes considers as 20 minutes!!!!

Comment: So, I tested using alertmanager with route tree and it seems to work. Please check again my answer...