# Export Prometheus Dashboard to send an email everyday automatically

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I am looking for a way to export Prometheus Dashboard to send an email every day automatically. I was able to create alerts in prometheus if anything goes down. At the same time I want to get an email everyday morning saying that everything is up and running.

Prometheus Dashboard

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alertmanager, different interval for different alert rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67628163/alertmanager-different-interval-for-different-alert-rules)

Comment: Felipe, I was actually able to create alerts for some of the instances. these alerts work only if they are down. I am actually looking to send an alert even though all instances are up and running not when something is down